# Javascript Canvas Flowcharting Project?

Tags: javascript, canvas, diagram, flowchart

I am looking for a Javascript project which makes use of canvas to allow the creation of diagrams/flowcharts in the browser.

Are there any active projects like that alive?

Comment: Do you mean *library* code or a javascript application (ala gliffy)?

Comment: @nimrodm Looking for a project which is developing an application. I want to use it, but would also be interested in contributing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[16 Javascript libraries for visualization](http://datavisualization.ch/tools/13-javascript-libraries-for-visualizations/) should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be also a commercial product from MindFusion which is also able to allow you to create flowcharts by JavaScript means: http://mindfusion.eu/features-jsdiagram.html, you might be also interested to see the tipps over at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558972/javascript-flowchart-library-for-workflow-visualization